# What's the most efficient way to verify http-response's data

Tags: javascript, rest, http, frontend, response

For example, when I make a http request below :

GET /myBox

And expecting a json format data response:

```
{
  a: (expecting a number),
  b: (expecting a string),
  c: (expecting 'apple', 'orange', or 'banana')
}
```

Then let's suppose our server program would never made mistakes. Should we need to verify the response's content data in case some net mistake? And if we should , what's the most efficient way to verify every response data.

Comment: You would basically just want to make sure that you got a 200 response code, and then make sure the data types are what you expect.

Comment: Is there any existing mechanism or library to make verifying every response date type more efficiency and more easier . @BooberBunz

Comment: Yes, "Google Gson" allows you to convert JSON in a Java Class... but I don't know about javascript.

Answer (score 3):

It would be best to create a predictable JSON payload that comes from your server in both success and error cases. For example if we run into an error perhaps a payload like so:

```
{ error: true, errorMessage: 'Some error message', payload: null }
```

For network related errors you need to handle the appropriate HTTP status codes in your client application. More on that here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status

If you want to develop a ridged schema for data passed from server to client you might want to look at a format that is more suited for that like Protobuf.

See:

- https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/protobufjs

Comment: Do you think it is necessary to check data types in every response.

Comment: No correctly designed API that returns JSON should require verifying the message contents every call you do. The endpoints of the API should be documented and have predictable output to handle error and success cases. If you are working with an API that does not have predictable output and checking the types of the data aides in your processing of the payload, may be then? But if you have that going on, you have bigger problems.

Answer (score 1):

In general, I think you can reasonably expect the response to be correct. Most developers would. If you deal with multiple servers and multiple implementors of those servers implementing the same protocol, maybe you can't trust it.

One way to validate the response in that case would be to use something like `json-schema`.

However, if you don't deal with many servers, maybe you can ask yourself under which conditions the response might be wrong. Do you have a reason not to trust it?

Comment: Yes, this is the problem I was struggling . Dose that really necessary to check the type every time even I'm sure the server didn't made mistake?

Comment: I can even write a middleware in client/browser side to check types in every response . But I'm doubt if this work is necessary.

Comment: I don't know 100% sure, but since you don't seem to have a special or unique case, I think you're in the clear just trusting the server. Most people do this.

Answer (score 0):

You kind of verify the response data when you set the data type of the fields that you expect in the response object.

for example:-

suppose this is your class that you are expecting as a response object:-

```
    public class example {
private String field1;
private int field2;
private bloolean field3;
}
```

If in the above fields you get field1 as a long instead of String then you will get an error which kind of checks whether the server is giving your expected response or not.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't tag this as a frontend and javascript question before.